# Linq to SQL: Multi-table join return type not generated by dbml

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, join, orm, return

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle a simple problem:
I have a simple LINQ join to two tables.  I know how to return the type for one table, since it is the same as the generated dbml class.  However, what if I want to return data from both tables- isn't there a way to return both and use their relationships?  Do I really have to create another return type to return the data from both tables?  FYI- I don't want to return an output parameter with the other table object; I'm also not really interested in returning an anonymous type.  What is the best practice recommendation?

```
    public IQueryable<Consumer_Question> GetQuestions(int subCategoryId)
    {
        //create DataContext
        MototoolsDataContext mototoolsDataContext = new MototoolsDataContext();
        mototoolsDataContext.Log = Console.Out;

        var subcategoriestag = (from subCatTag in mototoolsDataContext.Consumer_SubCategoriesTags
                                join tagQuestion in mototoolsDataContext.Consumer_TagQuestions on subCatTag.TagID equals tagQuestion.TagID
                                join question in mototoolsDataContext.Consumer_Questions on tagQuestion.QuestionsID equals question.ID
                                where subCatTag.SubCategoriesID == subCategoryId
                                orderby subCatTag.ID descending
                                select question);
                                //select new { question, tagQuestion });

        return subcategoriestag;
    }
```

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined your relationships in the LINQ-to-SQL designer then your above query doesn't need the join syntax at all, simply 'walk the tree' as needed, e.g.:

```
var subCategoriesTag = (
    from subCatTag in motoToolsDataContext
    from tagQuestion in subCatTag.TagQuestions
    from question in tagQuestion
    where subCatTag.SubCategoriesID == subcategoryId
    orderby subCatTag.ID descending
    select question
);
```

Note that the 2nd and 3rd 'from' statements are using the object from the previous one, since LINQ-to-SQL should already know about the relationship.

Without knowing more about your relationships it's harder to give a more exact answer. I had to make some assumptions about what the related properties were.

Comment: That begs the other question, if I have assigned relationships to my tables in the database already (primary keys, foreign keys) I noticed the the dbml generated class creates an association attribute for me for some of the relationships, not all.  So are you saying that if this relationship association is made correctly, that I can return the parent type and walk the children?  That's what I want!  I'll have to investigate the dbml association bug I seem to have.

Comment: So it turns out the problem with dbml generating my associations attributes for relationships was not because I forgot the foreign key portion of the relationship, but because I was missing a primary key designation on the parent table.  Now I am able to traverse the children object from question object and not worry about a custom return type to include all the data I want.  Cool.

Comment: @mytwocents: Glad to hear that, once it's all set up correctly LINQ-to-SQL is quite nice, it's still got some areas that are a little painful but it's finally getting some improvements for VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like what you are looking for is DataLoadOptions.LoadWith<>. That way you return your Question object and the related objects are populated at the same time through the defined associations. Something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Consumer_Question> GetQuestions(int subCategoryId)
{
    //create DataContext
    using (MototoolsDataContext mototoolsDataContext = new MototoolsDataContext())
    {
        mototoolsDataContext.Log = Console.Out;
        DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
        options.LoadWith<Consumer_Questions>(q => q.Consumer_TagQuestions);
        options.LoadWith<Consumer_TagQuestions>(tag => tag.Consumer_SubCategoriesTags);
        mototoolsDataContext.LoadOptions = options;

        var questions = (from subCatTag in mototoolsDataContext.Consumer_SubCategoriesTags
                                join tagQuestion in mototoolsDataContext.Consumer_TagQuestions on subCatTag.TagID equals tagQuestion.TagID
                                join question in mototoolsDataContext.Consumer_Questions on tagQuestion.QuestionsID equals question.ID
                                where subCatTag.SubCategoriesID == subCategoryId
                                orderby subCatTag.ID descending
                                select question);
                                //select new { question, tagQuestion });

        return questions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would work too, but isn't "LoadWith" typically for non-deferred loading?

Comment: Correct. It'd retrieve all the values together.